Is this graph theory proof regarding chip firing correct?
For my olympiad preparation i was reading a handout regarding chip firing games , A single player game which in the context is defined as
"Consider an infinite graph such that all vertices have finite degree. Let there be some
(non-negative amount) of
chips
or
tokens
on each vertex. In most cases, we only care
about finite graphs.
Now on this setup, consider the following game. A
firing
of a vertex
v
is a move in which
that vertex gives one chip to each of its neighbours if it can (i.e. has atleast
deg
(
v
)
chips
to give to its
neighbours
) .
Call a configuration
stable
if no vertices can be fired in it."
Now basically in each move we can choose any vertex which is capable of firing  and fire it  .
One of the theoroms regarding the game is
If the game is played on a simple graph and the game is finite[eventually gets to a stable configuration] , then there is atleast one vertex which is never fired ,
I had a proof of this which happens to be different from the one in the handout i was reading so it will be helpfull if someone could verify it
We induct on the number of vertices of the graph basically  say its $v$ we take $v=1$ as base case which is easy to prove for .
Now to prove for $v$ using $v-1,....,1$ we first say the graph is $G=(V,E)$ we can assume $G$ is connected  othewrise we can divide the game into two smaller graphs and use strong induction.
Once we know $G$ is connected  we consider the first vertex which had its last fire. Say its $v_1$ and suppose its neighouring vertices are $V_1,V_2,...,V_d$ all of these should fire atleast once after $v_1$ had its last fire , however that would make the number at $v_1 \geq $ deg $v_1$  for then the game to be finite $v_1$ must be fired atleast once causing contradiction
Can someone just verify if i am making a stupid mistake somewhere
Edit : I forgot to put the case of ifninite vertices but thats trivial for ifninite vertices to fire the game cannot be finite

I think your reasoning is correct. Note however that this is a proof by contradiction, and does not use induction. The bits about the base case and about the connected graphs are unnecessary. A bit more clarity about the actual assumption that is proved wrong by the contradiction would be good too.

@JaapScherphuis Ya i realized that as well , but i think the induction is necessary otherwise $v_1$ could be a disconnected vertex  but i should say that assume for contrary when proving for $v$ using previous

An isolated vertex can trivially/vacuously always be fired, so cannot be part of a stable configuration.

The game can be finite even if the graph is infinite, you can easily built trivial examples. The point is if the game is finite, then you can only fire a finite numbers of vertices, hence infinitely many vertices were never fired, hence the theorems holds for infinite graphs.

@ThomasLesgourgues Ya ur right i was actually writing a contradiction proof and i forgot to mention that so we assume every vertex fires atleast once
